# Marshalling C structures to C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, interop, pinvoke

Suppose I have a structure:

```
typedef struct {
float x;
float y;
float z;
int   ID;
} Vertex;
```

and a C++ function:

```
float first(Vertex* ptr, int length){ //really silly function, just an example
    Vertex u,v;
    u.x = ptr[0].x; //...and so on, copy x,y,z,ID
    v.x = ptr[1].x; 
    return (u.x * v.x + u.y * v.y + u.z * v.z);
    }


Vertex* another(float a, int desired_size){
    Vertex v = (Vertex*)malloc(desired_size*sizeof(Vertex));
    v[0].x = a;
    v[1].x = -a; //..and so on.. make some Vertices.
    return v;
}
```

First - my IDE. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, building a C# (4.0) application; The C++ part is also built in VS2010.

I know how to build a DLL of C/C++ code and use it in C# application, but until today I used only primitive arguments and return values like:

```
    [DllImport("library.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int simple(int a, int b);
```

Today I need to pass an **array** of **structs** (as in the example above).. and perhaps also receive one back..

How to I "translate" a C# class to a C struct (and vice versa) ??

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The struct can be declared like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Vertex {
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;
    public int ID;
}
```

Next you need to settle on a calling convention. Your C++ code is almost certainly compiled with `cdecl`. Let's stick with that.

The function first is easy to call from C#:

```
[DllImport("library.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern float first(Vertex[] vertices);
```

Note that you should not use `SetLastError` here–that's for Windows API functions. And there's no need to set the `CharSet` since there is no text here.

---

Now, for `another` things get more complex. If you can allocate the memory in the C# code then that is definitely the way to go.

```
void PopulateVertices(Vertex *vertices, int count)
{
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        vertices[i].x = ....
    }
}
```

On the C# side you declare it like this:

```
[DllImport("library.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void PopulateVertices(Vertex[] vertices, int count);
```

and call it like this

```
Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[2];
PopulateVertices(vertices, vertices.Length);
```

---

If you don't want to allocate on the C# side of the fence then do it like this:

1. Return a pointer from the C++ code and allocate it with `CoTaskMemAlloc`.
2. In C# declare the return value of the imported function as `IntPtr`.
3. Use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` and some pointer arithmetic to marshal the return array into a C# array.
4. Call `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem` to free the memory allocated in the native module.

But if you want my advice, try and stick to allocating the array in the managed code.

Comment: So - if possible -it's better (easier?) to allocate memory on the C# side and then pass the allocated space to the functions?

Comment: It's certainly a lot easier that way. In order to choose that solution you need to know the size of the array in advance. Sometimes you can call a function (that you provide) in the DLL to find out the required array size. But very often you just know how big you need the array to be from other information in your program.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this solution.

Comment: One more question: I have just read that structs are kept on the stack. If this is true, then probably the size of the passed array is (very) limited. What to do then?

Comment: Structs are not always kept on the stack. There is a common misconception that value types (a struct is a value type) always reside on the stack. Not true. In your case when you allocate an array, the contents of the array, it being an object, will live on the heap. Nothing to worry about here.

Comment: One **last** question: what if the Vertex struct has an array of floats i.e. `float info[3];` ??

Comment: declare it in C# in the struct as `float[] info;` and mark it with this attribute: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=3)]`  read all about UnmanagedType attribute here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx

Comment: This is a field in my C# Vertex struct: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 625)]
   public int[] tmp;`   ... is it read-only on the DLL side ? I cant seem to change those values.

Comment: This is very hard to deal with in comments and the question has long gone. You would be better off asking a new question with the relevant details to the immediate problem.

Answer (score 3):

It should be this easy:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Vertex {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    int   ID;
}

[DllImport("library.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern float first(Vertex[] verticies, int arrLen);
```

The issues you *may* run into would be if there is any packing done on the C version of the struct, and possibly the struct layout.  If the layout doesn't match, you may want to change it to `LayoutKind.Explicit` and use the `[FieldOffset(0)]` attribute on each field.  C would also have no idea, the length of the verticies array passed, so if that changes, you'd want to pass that along to the method.

To get an array back:

```
[DllImport("library.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern Vertex[] another(float a);
```

The marshaler handles all of the memory issues when passing arguments in, but returning the array it can't do anything.  Since the memory is allocated on the unmanaged heap, the GC has no idea about it, and you *will* wind up with a memory leak.  The marshaller will simply copy the native structs to the managed struct array, but it can't free the memory you've allocated with `malloc`.

The easiest way to get around it, if you can change the C++ code, would be to change the signature of `another` to take in an array of verticies (and the length of the array) instead of returning one.  I don't need to write out any code for you that does this, @DavidHeffernan has already done this in his answer, the part of the break.

Comment: and what about the other way around? no problem with memory allocation? pointers?

Comment: Returning an array allocated with the C++ malloc is simply not going to work.

Comment: My guess is that the marshaller might attempt to free the memory with `CoTaskMemFree`. Perhaps allocating it with `CoTaskMemAlloc` would do the job. I'd always prefer to allocate on the C# side of the fence.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I doubt it.  I think the marshaller does as little as possible to unmanaged memory, particularly when it's allocated with `malloc`, to prevent other code that would still expect that pointer to be valid.

Comment: That's what it does with a `string` return value. If you want to stop the marshaller deallocating then you use `IntPtr`. That is code for "I'm in charge here, hands off".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I wouldn't be shocked if I was wrong about it, since I'm very good at that.  I thought it only did that automatically with COM and not PInvoke.

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem.  Another big problem on both declarations is that there's no way to figure out how large the array is.  This can't work.

Comment: @HansPassant - I mentioned that briefly in my wall of text above, but I didn't bother updating the declaration (well, until now).  His bigger problem how the `another` code is defined.  There's a few options I've listed that should work, though.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I have changed the functions, so they may seem more 'realistic'